# Problem querying using AWS Amplify in Android with an existing AppSync API graphql

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I Have an AppSync using Apollo client in AWS and Auth with IAM, and i want to migrate it to Amplify using the existing AppSync resources with all the related logic (lambdas, functions, DynamoDB etc.). I went through the docs for how to setup Amplify (configure, init) using the AmplifyCLI, i managed to connect to the API and get the schema.grapghql, generated models, queries and mutations, and checked all the config files that are generated through the AmplifyCLI (amplifyconfiguration.json, awsconfiguration.json etc.) and all was successful. In the code i’ve added the plugin for API and the Auth using IAM and it said "initialized successfully", and i cant manage to do a simple query to that API resource.

```
 try {
        Amplify.addPlugin(AWSApiPlugin())
        Amplify.addPlugin(AWSCognitoAuthPlugin())
        Amplify.configure(applicationContext)
        Timber.tag("MyAmplifyApp").i("Initialized Amplify")
     } catch (error: AmplifyException) {
        Timber.tag("MyAmplifyApp").e(error, "Could not initialize Amplify")
     }
```

amplifyconfiguration.json

```
{
    "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/2.0",
    "Version": "1.0",
    "api": {
        "plugins": {
            "awsAPIPlugin": {
                "integration_eventsApi": {
                    "endpointType": "GraphQL",
                    "endpoint": [MyEndpoint],
                    "region": "us-east-1",
                    "authorizationType": "AWS_IAM"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "auth": {
        "plugins": {
            "awsCognitoAuthPlugin": {
                "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/0.1.0",
                "Version": "0.1.0",
                "IdentityManager": {
                    "Default": {}
                },
                "AppSync": {
                    "Default": {
                        "ApiUrl": [MyApiUrl],
                        "Region": "us-east-1",
                        "AuthMode": "AWS_IAM",
                        "ClientDatabasePrefix": "integration_eventsApi_AWS_IAM"
                    }
                },
                "CredentialsProvider": {
                    "CognitoIdentity": {
                        "Default": {
                            "PoolId": [MyPoolId],
                            "Region": "us-east-1"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "CognitoUserPool": {
                    "Default": {
                        "PoolId": "[MyPoolId]",
                        "AppClientId": "[AppClientId]",
                        "Region": "us-east-1"
                    }
                },
                "Auth": {
                    "Default": {
                        "authenticationFlowType": "CUSTOM_AUTH",
                        "socialProviders": [],
                        "usernameAttributes": [],
                        "signupAttributes": [],
                        "passwordProtectionSettings": {
                            "passwordPolicyMinLength": 8,
                            "passwordPolicyCharacters": [
                                "REQUIRES_LOWERCASE",
                                "REQUIRES_UPPERCASE",
                                "REQUIRES_NUMBERS",
                                "REQUIRES_SYMBOLS"
                            ]
                        },
                        "mfaConfiguration": "OFF",
                        "mfaTypes": [],
                        "verificationMechanisms": []
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

awsconfiguration.json

```
{
    "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/0.1.0",
    "Version": "0.1.0",
    "IdentityManager": {
        "Default": {}
    },
    "AppSync": {
        "Default": {
            "ApiUrl": "[MyApiUrl]",
            "Region": "us-east-1",
            "AuthMode": "AWS_IAM",
            "ClientDatabasePrefix": "integration_eventsApi_AWS_IAM"
        }
    },
    "CredentialsProvider": {
        "CognitoIdentity": {
            "Default": {
                "PoolId": "[MyPoolId]",
                "Region": "us-east-1"
            }
        }
    },
    "CognitoUserPool": {
        "Default": {
            "PoolId": "[MyPoolId]",
            "AppClientId": "[MyAppClientId]",
            "Region": "us-east-1"
        }
    },
    "Auth": {
        "Default": {
            "authenticationFlowType": "CUSTOM_AUTH",
            "socialProviders": [],
            "usernameAttributes": [],
            "signupAttributes": [],
            "passwordProtectionSettings": {
                "passwordPolicyMinLength": 8,
                "passwordPolicyCharacters": [
                    "REQUIRES_LOWERCASE",
                    "REQUIRES_UPPERCASE",
                    "REQUIRES_NUMBERS",
                    "REQUIRES_SYMBOLS"
                ]
            },
            "mfaConfiguration": "OFF",
            "mfaTypes": [],
            "verificationMechanisms": []
        }
    }
}
```

When i tried to make a Query or Mutation i get an error and have no idea why:

```
NonRetryableException{message=OkHttp client request failed., cause=null, recoverySuggestion=Irrecoverable error}
at com.amplifyframework.api.aws.AppSyncGraphQLOperation$OkHttpCallback.onResponse(AppSyncGraphQLOperation.java:146)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:539)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

I've checked other posts similar to this and online in general but couldn't fix this problem, maybe it has something to do with the Auth and the IAM user or role, but I have no prior knowledge in AWS unfortunately, so i don't know what to do.